# Scala: Extra functionality in a class, based on presence of constructor arguments

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, type-constraints

Let's say I have a "Base" class, and I want to add a "whoa" val to it.

But, the "whoa" val should ONLY be available if I provided a certain constructor argument (in this case, that argument is a function).

So, I created an extra "WhoaClass", containing the method "whoa", which "Base" can be implicitly converted to if need be. I just have to check that the constructor argument "func" is present (by checking that its type is not Null, which necessitates the ugly hack near the bottom)

My question is: Is there a better way to do this? Especially in terms of readability, and doing away with the ugly hack. I'm trying to do this still using constructor arguments and not some kind of builder. I'd really like the inline the "whoa" function into the Base class, instead of having it dangling in another class, which isn't very clear.

```
object WhoaTest {
    // the type of function I want to take
    type Func = Int => Option[Long]

    // this is the base class that takes a function
    case class Base[A <: Func](func: A = null) {}

    // this is the class with the extra method
    class WhoaClass(a: Long) {
        val whoa = "Whoa" + a.toString
    }

    // the implicit method to convert the base object into a WhoaClass with a whoa method
    implicit def enableWhoa[A <: Func](a: Base[A])
        (implicit ev: A =!= Null) // only enable this implicit if the function is present
        = new WhoaClass(a.func(50).get)

    // the hack for extra scala type checking
    trait =!=[A, B]
    implicit def neq[A, B] : A =!= B = null

    // Causes an ambiguity if the two types are the same
    implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =!= A = null
    implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =!= A = null
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It looks very much like some Java code that is pretending to be Scala -- the `null` is a dead giveaway.

Comment: I originally had an abstract trait called FuncNotPresent that extended Func. And then the constructor parameter was ``func: Option[Func] = Option.empty[FuncNotPresent]`` and I tested that the implicit evidence was FuncNotPresent, but all that just added to code bloat when there a nice convenient type lattice in Scala that gives Null a type. It really doesn't look anything (even remotely) like Java code. Sorry for the single strange null?

Comment: I recommend inspecting @applicius answer as it is pure Scala and, I believe, meets your needs.

Comment: My solution is more "scala" than his, but yes indeed, his answer is partially what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's using more complex feature Scala provides indeed. For me it's not because it can be done that it should. I think ajusting complexity of solution is a key point especially when other people can then read code, or if it would have to be maintained. There I don't see reason to go for more complex solution.

Comment: Yes I agree. But I think automatically calling it java in scala's clothing because of a null is wrong, though. I don't think null should be discouraged in Scala, because while it's not especially functional, it's still somewhat of an optimization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `null` testing is a quite 'unusual' habit in Scala. Then I think you'd better have a base trait and factory functions in companion object.

```scala
trait Base { /* common code, unconditionnally */ }

object Base {
  def apply(): Base = new Base {} // factory when no arg

  def apply(a: Long): Base = new Base {
    overide lazy val toString = s"Whoa: $a"
  }
}

// Then can do ...
val base1: Base = Base() // first apply factory
val base2: Base = Base(1L) // second factory
```

Comment: It's okay, but not exactly complete. I think I will do the factory functions in the companion object, but "Base" will be a class, and I will do ``type BaseWithWhoa = Base with Whoa`` (making Whoa a trait with a whoa function), and the second apply function will return a "BaseWithWhoa". Sound good?

Comment: I don't see the point of have such type member, maybe you don't have mention the motivation for in the question. For me simpler is better.

Comment: Yeah, the general pattern you suggested is what I want. Thank you. (But I do have to have ``class Whoa extends Base`` and then I return it from the respective apply's.